# Do not get PAYMENT.SALE.PENDING or PAYMENT.SALE.DENIED WebHook event types from PayPal

Tags: paypal, sandbox, recurring, paypal-webhooks

I tested recurring payments in sandbox. I created customer paypal account with zero ballance and without Bank accounts. When I made recurring payment from this account. 
I created profile with some initial payment (setup_fee). And set max_fail_attempts to 1. By default, PayPal does not activate the profile if the initial payment amount fails. But my profile successful activated and has status ACTIVE instead PENDING. And I received on WebHook PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event type. I expected get some FAIL event type (PAYMENT.SALE.PENDING or PAYMENT.SALE.DENIED), because customer account have not enough money. Why it happened? 
I need to Cancel recurring payment profile if does not enough money in customer account.
[Customer PayPal account after payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUMb1.png)

Comment: The best way is to create an MTS ticket. They will help you check...

Comment: Problem resolved. In sandbox environment, as long as you have available funding resource, the payment will continue to success.  In live environment, if you card does not have sufficient balance, the payment will fail.